# Oracle format conversions from to_char TO (to_timestamp or to_Date)

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT Owner
     FROM
            TABLEX
     WHERE  (
               ( To_Char(From_Date,'YYYYMM') <= '201707' )
                 And
               ( To_Char(To_Date,'YYYYMM') >= '201707' )
            );
```

Oracle Query:

`FROM_DATE`, `To_Date` is in *Timestamp* format.This query is working fine, but my manager told me to_char Format comparison slow down performance of query and he asked me to use either date format OR timestamp format for conversions. I tried different combinations, but not able to identify. Please suggest.
Some tries I have done.

`select to_date('201707','YYYYMM') from DUAL`.
This gives me (`01-JUL-2017`) , but I have to check with all values greater than and less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the query as efficient as possible, use constants of the same data type as the columns being compared. This eliminates the need for the database to perform a type conversion for each row:

```
Select owner From tablex
 Where From_Date < To_Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  And To_Date >= To_Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: NO, actually I have to consider all cases where From_Date is less than equal to month of July ,so it can be a date from june, July, etc. and same is case with To_Date, To_Date can be July, AUGUST, September, etc.                                                                                                               Example of From_Date = '04-JUL-17 11.59.59.000000000 PM', '08-JUN-17 11.59.59.000000000 PM'                                                                                                             To_Date = '08-JUL-17 11.59.59.000000000 PM, '10-JUL-17 01.39.59.000000000 PM'

Comment: Understood. Please see updated answer. Do notice that the dates are now different in the two predicates.

Comment: I think you have not got the purpose of Query.

Comment: My understanding is that `From_Date` can be any value less than August 1; in other words, any time prior to July, or any time during July. `To_Date` must be any value greater than or equal to the first instant of July.

Comment: Suppose From_Date is = '01-AUG-17 08.00.00.000000000 AM' and To_Timestamp('20170801','yyyymmdd') expression gives me "'01-AUG-17 12.00.00.000000000 AM"                                                                                                              So , In this way August record will also be taken.

Comment: Actually, that is not correct. 01-AUG-17 12.00.00.000000000 AM represents the first instant of August 1; midnight, in other words. It is _prior_ to 8am. If you run the query I provided, I think you'll find it does exactly what is intended.

Comment: Yes, I also found the same. But I am not able to understand why '01-AUG-17 12.00.00.000000000 AM ' < ''01-AUG-17 08.00.00.000000000 AM'

Comment: It is convention not to use 0 for midnight when displaying time in 12-hour AM/PM format. If the time were displayed in 24-hour format, it would be 00.00.00.000000000.

Comment: Run this to see what I mean: `Select To_Char(To_Timestamp('201708','yyyymm'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual`

Comment: I know Oracle defaults to the first day of the month if it isn't specified, but including the day in the constant value might be clearer; and given the OP's confusion I'd be tempted to include the time portion as well (as HH24). Or even use a timestamp literal.

Comment: Thanks @Kirby for your valuable guide, it was really helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the suggestion. I've tweaked the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Trunc` function instead of `To_Char`:

```
SELECT Owner
         FROM
                TABLEX
         WHERE  (
                   ( Trunc(From_Date,'YYYYMM') <= '201707' )
                     And
                   ( Trunc(To_Date,'YYYYMM') >= '201707' )
                );
```

Comment: The syntax you've shown is invalid; you can't provide 'YYYYMM' as an argument to `trunc()`, it'll get "ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers". Even if you only passed in `'MM'` to truncate to the first of the month, you're still comparing a date on the left-hand side (even though the table columns are timestamps) with a string literal. If you're lucky the date will be implicitly converted to a string in the matching format; but even if that happens you're preventing an index on those columns being used, and in the more likely event it doesn't match you'll get incorrect results.